# Is it possible to tell keycloak to create its own database somewhere else and not use the embedded H2?

Tags: java, mysql, keycloak

So basically I would tell it that at `localhost:8090` I have a mysql server and build & use your database there.

Is it possible or I need my own custom database and create some userstorage SPIs?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Keycloak to use an external database.

It's well written in the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db).

For your MySQL database, you would start Keycloak using the following parameter.

```bash
bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --db mysql --db-url jdbc:mysql://localhost:8090/[DATABASE NAME] --db-username [DATABASE USERNAME] --db-password [DATABASE PASSWORD]
```

When running Keycloak as a docker container, the command would be something like this:

```bash
docker run -p 8080:8080 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.5 start --db mysql --db-url jdbc:mysql://[DATABASE IP/FQDN]:[DATABASE PORT]/[DATABASE NAME] --db-username [DATABASE USERNAME] --db-password [DATABASE PASSWORD]
```